# SharePoint List - Get Manager Information

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have a SharePoint List with 2 columns (people or group) this list is to track users who make error in their job and we want to inform the user and his/her manager.

Column 1 –  user who made an error 
& am trying to get this user’s manager information in the Column 2 automatically from AD

And then once the item is saved- an email notification has to be sent to both the user from column 1 & 2 and NOT to the person who is creating the item.

we don't want to use SP designer. 
I just stated to user O365 users and trying to achieve this via Flow.

Thanks in advanced for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Flow has 'Office 365 Users' connectors that allow you to gain information about users, including their manager. For the 'Get User Profile' step, once you enter the variable for the user's upn, the 'Get Manager' step will configure on its own. Using those, I imagine related steps in your use case might look something close to this:

[image]

Cheers,

-Drew

Comment: Thanks Drew, 
I had exactly the same flow, but the problem is the manager is not getting the email from the flow. 
And the Manger info is not getting populated or added in the list. Any suggestion on what can be done to fix this...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is this the case for all users? Are managers otherwise set correctly in profiles as your organization is syncing them from Active Directory?

Comment: i re-did the the flow and it works now. The Manager did get an email. 
So what am trying now is to get the manager name to be added to the SharePoint list item.. is that possible ?

Comment: You should be able to use the same variable generated from the 'Get Manager' action and reference it as dynamic content in an 'Update Item' action. Though depending on the structure of your flow, you may need to use a 'Get Item' action to query for the correct item prior to that.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have the exact same structure of the flow that you attached here. So i guess i should be adding an action under Get manager (v2) but am not sure which dynamic content to be used.